# How to get Stripe token in the controller of MVC framework?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I am using CodeIgniter and I can't get the Stripe Token in the controller function.

I got the PHP Error :
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: stripeToken

Filename: controllers/App.php
Line Number: 339

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<form action="<?php echo site_url('app/save/'.$event['code']);?>" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
     Please pay:
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Pay</button>
</form>
```

I checked the action URL in front-end. It shows the link:
https://www.example.com/enrollment/index.php/app/save/EVENT_A

This is the correct link to my controller.

The JS: (I have changed the key here)

```
<script>
  // Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('my_correct_key');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements({
  locale: 'en',
});

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {hidePostalCode: true});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      console.log(errorElement.textContent);
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        console.log(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

In my Controller:

```
    public function save($event_code){
            $token=$_POST['stripeToken'];
        echo $token;

    }
```

I can't get the token here. I am not familiar with CodeIgniter.  What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Codeigniter Stripe Payment Integration Example - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .panel-title {
        display: inline;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        .display-table {
            display: table;
        }
        .display-tr {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .display-td {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 61%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <h1>Codeigniter Stripe Payment Integration Example <br/> ItSolutionStuff.com</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                <div class="panel-heading display-table" >
                    <div class="row display-tr" >
                        <h3 class="panel-title display-td" >Payment Details</h3>
                        <div class="display-td" >                            
                            <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://i76.imgup.net/accepted_c22e0.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')){ ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                            <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <form role="form" action="/stripePost" method="post" class="require-validation"
                                                     data-cc-on-file="false"
                                                    data-stripe-publishable-key="<?php echo $this->config->item('stripe_key') ?>"
                                                    id="payment-form">

                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label> <input
                                    class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label> <input
                                    autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-number' size='20'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group cvc required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>CVC</label> <input autocomplete='off'
                                    class='form-control card-cvc' placeholder='ex. 311' size='4'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Month</label> <input
                                    class='form-control card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Year</label> <input
                                    class='form-control card-expiry-year' placeholder='YYYY' size='4'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12 error form-group hide'>
                                <div class='alert-danger alert'>Please correct the errors and try
                                    again.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Pay Now ($100)</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $form         = $(".require-validation");
  $('form.require-validation').bind('submit', function(e) {
    var $form         = $(".require-validation"),
        inputSelector = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                         'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                         'textarea'].join(', '),
        $inputs       = $form.find('.required').find(inputSelector),
        $errorMessage = $form.find('div.error'),
        valid         = true;
        $errorMessage.addClass('hide');

        $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(el);
      if ($input.val() === '') {
        $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
        $errorMessage.removeClass('hide');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });

    if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }

  });

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            $('.error')
                .removeClass('hide')
                .find('.alert')
                .text(response.error.message);
        } else {
            var token = response['id'];
            $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
            $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    }

});
</script>
</html>


    /**
     * Get All Data from this method.
     *
     * @return Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('my_stripe');
    }

    /**
     * Get All Data from this method.
     *
     * @return Response
    */
    public function stripePost()
    {
        require_once('application/libraries/stripe-php/init.php');

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->config->item('stripe_secret'));

        \Stripe\Charge::create ([
                "amount" => 100 * 100,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $this->input->post('stripeToken'),
                "description" => "Test payment from itsolutionstuff.com." 
        ]);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Payment made successfully.');

        redirect('/my-stripe', 'refresh');
    }
```